# Allowed memory size in Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework, memory-leaks

Problem: When customer is logged in and I save product in admin panel, then refreshing frontend and error showing:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88 bytes) in /home/staging/public/kralengroothandel/app/code/local/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 297
```

or

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83 bytes) in /home/staging/public/kralengroothandel/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 196
```

Pdo.php lines, where problems occurs:

```
public function _execute(array $params = null)
{
    try {
        if ($params !== null) {
            return $this->_stmt->execute($params);
        } else {
            return $this->_stmt->execute();
        }
```

second place:

```
public function fetchAll($style = null, $col = null)
    {
        if ($style === null) {
            $style = $this->_fetchMode;
        }
        try {

            if ($style == PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) {

                if ($col === null) {

                    $col = 0;
                }
                return $this->_stmt->fetchAll($style, $col);
            } else {
                return $this->_stmt->fetchAll($style);
            }
```

Element.php:

```
 if (!$desc) {
     return false;
 }
```

I have same code and database on local machine, but I don't have this problem.

memory_limit set up on 512M and I guess problem not here, because the Zend_Db lib sets an internal memory limit. So I try to put `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` in Pdo.php, but it's also doesn't help. I have OneStepCheckout extension(maybe it's reason I have this problem). I use Ngnix. Maybe somebody has same errors?

php-fpm.conf on my server:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 4
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 2

request_terminate_timeout = 0
request_slowlog_timeout = 0

chdir = /

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 128M
php_admin_value[post_max_vars] = 64000
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 3600
php_admin_value[realpath_cache_size] = 16m
```

Comment: Try to set memory limit in .htasscess file in your root directory, like this "php_value memory_limit 1024M"

Comment: I forgot to say, I use ngnix.

Answer (score 0):

increase the size in php.ini

```
php_value memory_limit 64M // add the memory limit here 
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Comment: I did update, do I need to put it in the end of my php-fpm.conf file?

Comment: Under your conf file make sure that is not commented ? like if something is start with # remove it  also after the changes try to look in to your phpinfo file

Comment: memory_limit in php.ini 2000+M and max_execution_time more then 360 days, but error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `shell/abstract.php` on how Magento configures php programmatically:

```
/**
 * Parse .htaccess file and apply php settings to shell script
 *
 */
protected function _applyPhpVariables()
{
    $htaccess = $this->_getRootPath() . '.htaccess';
    if (file_exists($htaccess)) {
        // parse htaccess file
        $data = file_get_contents($htaccess);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_value\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
        preg_match_all('#^\s+?php_flag\s+([a-z_]+)\s+(.+)$#siUm', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($matches) {
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                @ini_set($match[1], str_replace("\r", '', $match[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the php `ini_set` instruction, not the Zend library methods, so this is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have server rights, then kindly add below code in magento_root/index.php file
at top.

```
    ini_set("memory_limit",'1024M');
```

you will not get anymore error regarding to memory limit :)

cheers!!

Comment: not helping, cause as I wrote before - Zend_Db lib sets an internal memory limit.

Comment: I was getting same error before.
you will have to write code in your root/index.php file before magento php compare code.
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

Let me know if you still facing this problem... 
if ( preg_match('/designer/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
{
 $ary = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $ary = explode('designer', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/designer".$ary[1]);
 exit;
}

Comment: I write it just before compare or in the very top, whatever error still there.